# I wanted to know how to identify the amount of storage an iPhone has in total - not the storage remaining - using Swift UI

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

Thanks! I was not able to find much documentation on this online. I appreciate the help.

Comment: The key you want from MartinR's answer is `volumeTotalCapacityKey`.

Answer (score -1):

```
func deviceRemainingFreeSpaceInBytes() -> NSNumber {
          let documentDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
          let systemAttributes = NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfFileSystemForPath(documentDirectoryPath.last as String, error: nil)
          return systemAttributes[NSFileSystemFreeSize] as NSNumber
        }
```

try this. Hope this helps

Comment: This returns the available storage, not the total storage. It also looks like it was copied verbatim from another question. Please do not do that. If the question is a duplicate and there is an answer elsewhere, vote to close the question as a duplicate and link to the previous answer.